# Method to decode XML entities?

Tags: php, xml, decode, xml-entities

I am working on a PHP 5.3 production server, so `html_entity_decode($, ENT_XML1)` is not available.

My question is simple: What is the conversion method for example for `&#159;` to a byte?

Comment: 159 is a control character

Comment: Are you sure `html_entity_decode` function isn't available in your php version? it's built-in and available since php v4.3. have you tried it with `function_exists()`? in any case, have a look at this -> http://uk3.php.net/html_entity_decode#51055

Comment: @LatheesanKanes It's available, but `ENT_XML1` to decode any decimal entity is not, so it misses some.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = preg_replace('/&#(\d+);/me', 'chr(\\1)', $str);
```

Seems to be a hack for this problem.
Found at http://php.net/html_entity_decode#47371.

But I still don't understand the logic behind it.